# Append text to start of last line

Tags: linux, text-processing, text-formatting

How do I append `something =` to the start of the last line of a text file in Linux

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

to

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
something = DDD
```

Comment: That’s prepending, not appending.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$ sed '$ s/^/something = /' file
AAA
BBB
CCC
something = DDD
```

With GNU sed (Linux), the file can be edited in place by:

```
sed -i '$ s/^/something = /' file
```

To edit the file in place on MacOS or BSD, use instead:

```
sed -i "" -e '$ s/^/something = /' file
```

#### How it works:

- `s/^/something = /` is  a substitute command. It tells sed to look for the beginning of the line, marked by `^`, and replace it with `something =` .
- The `$` before the substitute command is a [sed address](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html), and it tells sed to apply the substitute command only to the last line in the file.

Comment: I think you need to add `-ie` to actually edit the file. This will not actually edit the file instead put output on the terminal.

Comment: @Pacifist OK.  I added info on editing-in-place.

Comment: thank you for your help